# How to make an SSD out of a Use Case with only 1 class in the Domain Model?

Tags: oop

As a project in college, we have to make an application. It is made using Agile. We build the application Use Case (Refered to as UC) by Use Case, from analysis to design and the programming. The first UC is logging in. However, we are having quite a lot of trouble and our professor simply tells us to figure it out ourselves and Google is our best friend.

The Use Case: post-condition is 'user is logged in'.

> 1: User wants to log in.
>
> 2: System asks username and password.
>
> 3: User gives username and password.
>
> 4: System validates using a database.
>
> 5: System shows username.
>
> 6: System shows a menu (link to further UC's)

From this Use Case alone, we have to make a first iteration. We make a domain model, System Sequence Diagram, Operation Contract if possible, Sequence Diagram and Design Class Diagram.

From this information alone, we only have 1 class in our domain model (player with attributes 'username' and 'password'.
Is it possible to make a System Sequence Diagram out of this or should we have at least 2 classes?

This is literally our first application and we haven't seen anything about database integration yet.

SSD: https://imgur.com/a/Yi7g9">SSD
'Speler' translates to 'player', 'geefGegevens' translate to 'supplyData' (not a direct translaton, the user supplies username and password)

Comment: Please don't use all those acronyms, you're severely limiting the number of people willing to and able to help you.

Comment: Changed them. Honestly, the people that are able to help us out with this should know those acronyms anyways, but I see your point.

Comment: Also, do you mind removing that downvote? Ironically, it also limits the amount of people wanting to help out.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, I only left that comment. I also see your point about the acronyms.

Comment: Alright, sorry then. I don't suppose you could help us out, since you're a software architect?

Comment: The general way this type of scenario plays out is that your code retrieves, usually through a repository, the salt and hash of the password that was stored the last time the password was changed (or when the account was created), hashes the newly typed in password along with the same salt and checks if the hashes are identical. I can see how I would like to spread that out over several classes with their own limited responsibilities but I'm afraid I cannot tell you how that fits into all those concepts you're talking about.

Comment: I would have a model for the person login in, a repository that can retrieve the salt and hash of an existing user (or nothing if the user does not exist), a service that would take the username, call to the repository and ask for the salt+hash, then a different service that I would give the salt+the new password to that does the hashing.

Comment: We only have to do the analysis and design of this UC for next class. A repo does sound like a good idea but it still boils down to that integration with the database via a persistence layer. Perhaps the professor might answer now I have a general idea on how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: There are some alternative routes, such as the combination of username and password not matching the information from the database or the user simply doesn't exist in the system yet. I think adding that repository might be the best solution.

Comment: Just make sure that when you get down to the details, design the responses so that the user interface only says something along the lines of "Either the user does not exist or the password was incorrect", don't ever tell the user which one it is even if your code knows it, for security reasons.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I might add a shortcut to a screen where the user can make an account if they want to. Something along the lines of 'No account yet? Click "here" to sign up'

Comment: Yes, and in the context of security, what you want to do there is to respond with something along the lines of "If the email does not exist in the system then a new account has been created for you and an email has been sent to your inbox", don't leak information about accounts, even their presence or absence is a security leakage.

Comment: The application won't be released or anything. It will be reviewed by a group of professors. Since we are freshmen (first year), the application will be rather simple. It's a game of Mastermind where you should be able to save your game, challenge other players (compare scores) and select difficulty. Security isn't really an issue but it's good practice to always include it I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [System Sequence Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_sequence_diagram) is independent from the classes you will use for implementation. It shows the sequence for a particular use-case.

In your case, the use-case is "logging in" and you presumably need to handle steps like:

- System asks for user name and password
- User supplies user name
- User supplies password
- System responds with success or loops back on failure, ...

Maybe if you post the sequence diagram you've made so far someone can give you a better answer.

Comment: I've added the SSD.

Answer (score 1):

In my idea and based on your explanation, you have more than one class in domain model with one Use Case.

First can be **Internet User**: Internet user is different from system user. System user is your system valid user and he/she has username and password, but everyone from internet can make a request to login to your system (maybe successful login or not), so the actor of **logging in** use case is not System User, it is Internet User. Internet user can have it's own attributes like ip_address, login_request_datetime and number_of_login_tries and etc.

Second is **System User**: System User inherited from Internet User. After successful login, the Internet user changed to System User. System User is not the actor of **logging in** use case. System User is actor for other use cases of system (in control panel)

For sequence diagram:

If you want to provide the sequence diagram of first phase (inception or gathering information phase - however I am afraid that it is Agile !!!), you have communicated with System Class. Meaning that you have only actor classes and the system class in your sequence diagram and your actors are communicated with system.

But in the sequence diagram of analysis phase, your system class is decompose to your **Analysis Classes**. Determining the analysis classes is related to your methodology. For example you can have Boundary classes (UIs, Forms such as login form and etc.), Control classes (or Business Login) and Entity classes. So your actors are communicated with Boundary classes and Boundary classes are communicated with Control classes and so on.

Therefor, in analysis phase, you have many classes (**Analysis Classes**) to provide sequence diagram.

Comment: While most of the information you provided is a little above our level for now, since this is the first iteration and there will be workshops about the whole process, we thought adding a (player) repository might solve the problem for now. In later iterations, it will be refined. Would this work?

Comment: Yes, you can. However I believe that there is no need to SDD in iteration 1 (in Agile methodologies).

Comment: I see your point, but since they will grade it, I'll make a version with a repository as well. It might just as well be what he wanted us to do